# Error on first login attempt - Spring Security (With Grails)

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm creating an app using Grails 3 and SpringSecurity Core, as of now there is only a custom login page (named auth.gsp so that it can overwrite the default spring security auth.gsp, it does not have the Remember-me option), a index page with the message "Welcome" and a logout button, and some domain classes (the SpringSecurity User, Role and UserRole, beside some other classes that does nothing right now).

Every time I run the app after restarting the computer, on the first login attempt I'm redirected to a error (http://localhost:8080/error) such as this one:

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 27 14:58:55 GMT-03:00 2016There was an unexpected error (type=None, status=999).No message available

If I erase the "/error" and go to the URL http://localhost:8080/ it works fine (it shows me the Welcome page), and if I logout and try to login again it does not show the error page (even if I run stop-app and run it again, the error page will not show anymore, I have to restart the computer for it to show again).

Anyone has any idea why is this happening? There is absolutly nothing running besides SpringSecurity, the custom auto.gsp and the auto generated domain classes. Is it an issue with the plugin?

The auth.gsp form is as follow:

```
<form action="${postUrl ?: '/login/authenticate'}" method="POST" class="login-form">
    <input class="form-control"
      name="${usernameParameter ?: 'username'}"  placeholder="User" type="text"/>
    <input class="form-control" name="${passwordParameter ?: 'password'}"
      placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
    <button class="btn ing-btn-primary login-btn-confirm" type="submit">
                    Login
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like you may have something on the main page or called initially that may require authentication. i.e. an extra rule that you need to add to your application.groovy configuration for spring security. https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/ take a look through here and look for debugging and see if the output gives you a reason as to why you are ending up there. There is nothing wrong with the plugin. Saying that I am basing it on 3.1.4 grails and latest spring security core

Comment: It really was, I changed the mapping in application.groovy and modified the restrictions, the bug stopped, thanks.